# Showing a notification that only appears on the wear device

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

Is there a way to create a notification that will only appear on the android wear device (and not in the mobile device)?

Comment: Hehe, I wrote those 2 questions. they are different; this one is asking if it is possible to show a notification ONLY on an android wear device, and the one you linked asks if it possible to have 1 notification with different text between android wear and mobile device

Comment: By screen size you can detect your application running on which device\

Comment: How can this help me to not show the notification on the mobile device?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at answer in your other question.
[Different text for the wear device and the mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578714/android-wear-have-a-different-text-for-the-wear-device-and-the-mobile-device)

Basically just ignore step to make a notification on your phone (with `setLocalOnly()`) and you will achieve exactly the result your are looking for (only notification on Wear device).